# How to copy and change the name of a PDF file by using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf

I have a set of pdf files that has a string after a text, something like:

```
example1.pdf
    This is your name
    John Doe
```

So I want to change the name of all my PDFs so that, for example, it will appear instead of example1.pdf to appear John Doe.pdf

I have made the following program:

```
def main():
    pdfFiles=[]
    for filename in os.listdir('C:\\programs'):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfFiles.append(filename)
    os.chdir('C:\\programs')
    regex="This is your name"
    lista=[]
    pdfWriter=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
    for filename in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileobj=open(filename,"rb")
        pdfReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
        page=pdfReader.getPage(0)
        text=page.extractText()
        before_keyword,keyword,after_keyword=text.partition(regex)
        list=after_keyword
        a=list.split("\n")
        pdfWriter.addPage(page)
        pdfoutput=open(a[3],"wb")
        pdfWriter.write(pdfoutput)
        pdfoutput.close()
```

I have managed that `a[3]` contains the name of the person, but when I run my program I get the following error:

```
return self.flattenedPages[pageNumber]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix this?